# Hadoop, mapreduce java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am trying to use two mappers and one reducer. 
I got this following error : 
I want to combine several keys and I am expecting to get the output for its summation based on each key. I don't know which part is wrong. It would be really appreciated if you can find some error for my code.

```
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:602)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:106)
    at CounterTwoMapper.map(CounterTwoMapper.java:28)
    at CounterTwoMapper.map(CounterTwoMapper.java:8)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingMapper.run(DelegatingMapper.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:673)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(S
```

.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;


public class CounterMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
     {
        private Text outkey = new Text();

      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException
      {
          try {


                if(value.toString().startsWith("BibNumber"))
                {
                    return;
                }

                String data[] = value.toString().split(",");

                String BookType = data[2];
                String DateTime = data[5];

                SimpleDateFormat frmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

                Date creationDate = frmt.parse(DateTime);
                frmt.applyPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
                String dateTime = frmt.format(creationDate);

                //outkey.set(BookType + " " + dateTime);
                outkey.set(BookType + " " + dateTime);

                //outUserId.set(userId);
                context.write(outkey, new IntWritable(1));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
     }


import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

 public class CounterTwoMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
 {

     private Text outkey = new Text();

     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
  throws IOException, InterruptedException
  {

      if(value.toString().startsWith("BibNumber"))
        {
            return;
        }

        String data[] = value.toString().split(",");

        String BibNum = data[0];
        String Title = data[1];

        outkey.set(BibNum + " " + Title);
        context.write(outkey, new IntWritable(1));
  }
 }
```

import java.io.IOException;

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context;

 public class CounterReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> 
 {


  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context ) 
  throws IOException, InterruptedException
  {
      int count=0;

 for(IntWritable value: values)
   {
       count++;
   }

   context.write(key, new IntWritable(count));
  }
 }

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.MultipleInputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class MultiInputFile extends Configured implements Tool 
{

 public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
 Configuration conf = new Configuration();
 Job job = new Job(conf, "aggprog");
 job.setJarByClass(MultiInputFile.class);
 MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[0]),TextInputFormat.class,CounterMapper.class);
 MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[1]),TextInputFormat.class,CounterTwoMapper.class);

 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
 job.setReducerClass(CounterReducer.class);
 job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
 job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
 job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

 return (job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


  int ecode = ToolRunner.run(new MultiInputFile(), args);
  System.exit(ecode);


 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the `OutputValueClass` as `Text` while actually outputting a `IntWritable`. Set it to `IntWritable` instead in your `MultiInputFile` Class.

`job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);`